# How to draw graphics outside window (OpenGL glfw)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I want to know how I can draw opengl graphics outside the main drawing window (GLFW). An example can be seen with the ImGUI library. With the ImGui docking, you are able to drag the panels outside the main window. How does ImGui go about doing that; drawing graphics outside the main window?. How can I achieve this with openGL and glfw? I am using c++ btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For OpenGL you always need a context to draw in. Such a context is either an offscreen context (all drawing to that context are not visible on the screen) or a context that is bound to the canvas of a window.

How that window looks like depends on the used library and system, but you never can draw outside of that window/canvas.

ImGUI is a library that composes a UI using various components/primitives within the OpenGL context. The UI elements of ImGUI are no OS related UI elements. And ImGUI windows are nothing that will be recognized by the OS as a window, but just a collection of pixels in the OpenGL context that form the visual appearance of the UI. ImGUI has the same limitations you have, it can't draw outside of the main window of the OpenGL context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But then how do the docking panels in ImGui appear outside the window? What is happening? How can I do a similar thing?

Comment: @AliAman I currently can't tell you how this particular feature is solved in ImGUI, because I didn't have time to look at its code. But there are only a few ways how that could be done. E.g. a second window with an OpenGL context, where the window has now borders and is semi-transparent, but then you still draw within that window. Or rendering that portion of the UI into an image and pass it to the Drag&Drop API of the OS, which den draws it semi-transparent. But no matter how it is solved the OpenGL part of the drawing will always happen within the boundaries of the context/window.

Comment: @AliAman I did a first look at their code. To my understanding, they create a frameless window on demand if you a window/component moves partially outside of the boundaries of the window. It might be that a certain OS or framework like GLFW/SDL provides additional tools to accomplish that. But that's out of the scope of OpenGL itself. There is a huge amount of engineering behind that functionality in ImGUI. Because you need to sync the drawing between multiple OpenGL windows if they overlap and move.

Comment: Thanks a lot t.niese. Your informative reply really helped!